# How do I check if two columns match base on them having the same string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to analyze a dataset I have that looks like this:

```
 PRESSEDKEY     PALABRA   COLOR  KEYCORR      RT
     V           HORNO     blue     a        198
```

Basically, I need to check if the pressed key matches the correct key (the correct key is in lower case but that doesn't matter). So here the pressed key was V instead of A so the result is incorrect. The options are A, V and R.
I also need to see the difference in reaction time between the correct and incorrect times once I get it.

How do I manage to do this?

I thought of this but this doesn't work and might be too ardous to try with each key unless that's the only way to do it:

```
pressed_key = filtered_data['PRESSEDKEY']
keycorr = filtered_data['KEYCORR']

def correctV(pressed_key, keycorr):
   if pressed_key.str.contains('V'):
       if keycorr.str.contains('v'):
           print('Correct')
       else:
           print('Incorrect')
```

Comment: Did you try with `pressed_key.lower() == keycorr.lower()` ?

Comment: @FrancoMorero That returns AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Please revisit the tutorials on PANDAS.  These will show you how to compare columns -- and, perhaps even more important how to do it as a whole-column operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could go about it is to create a column that will show whether PRESSEDKEY equals KEYCORR, and then get the mean RT (reaction time) per group:

```
# Assign Y/N
df.loc[df['PRESSEDKEY'].str.lower() == df['KEYCORR'],'correct'] ='Y'
df.fillna('N',inplace=True)

# Compare RT
df.groupby('correct')['RT'].mean()
```

---

```
>>> df

  PRESSEDKEY PALABRA COLOR KEYCORR   RT correct
0          V   HORNO  blue       a  198       N
1          R   HORNO  blue       r  231       Y
2          A   HORNO  blue       a  325       Y
3          V   HORNO  blue       v  111       Y
4          V   HORNO  blue       a  231       N
5          R   HORNO  blue       r  213       Y
6          A   HORNO  blue       v  251       N
7          V   HORNO  blue       a  198       N


>>> df.groupby('correct')['RT'].mean() 

correct
N    219.5
Y    220.0
Name: RT, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was very useful. However, when I'm trying to get the mean it says "pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate", how can I fix this since 'correct' is not numeric?

Comment: Welcome. Seems like your RT column is not numeric. Try converting it numeric first and let me know if the error persists. check out [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) link.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did have to convert it first so now it works.